# Google Apps Script returns file from drive as application/pdf instead of original filetype

Tags: google-apps-script

When running my script I get the error `Converting from application/pdf to application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet is not supported. (line 6, file "Code")`

The original file is no PDF but an excel worksheet. I tried different file with different types and every file returned as PDF.

Here is my code:

```
function sendTimelist() {
  var emailAddress = 'some@mail.com';
  var mailReplyTo = 'somemore@mail.com';
  var subject = 'Timelist';
  var message = 'Here is my timelist!';
  var timelist = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1v7EShuCrjrEa8BxW2JGCRDUwuIsUk03fnvvYEVntlvM").getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo: mailReplyTo, name: attachmentName, attachments: [timelist] };
  var attachmentName = 'Timelist.xlsx';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I focused on the length of your file ID. Your file ID is `1v7EShuCrjrEa8BxW2JGCRDUwuIsUk03fnvvYEVntlvM`. The length is 44. In the case of Excel file in Google Drive, the length of ID is 28. And the case of Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, Slide), the length of ID is 44.
When Google Docs files are downloaded without the assignment of export format, the format automatically becomes PDF.

I thought that you might try to send Spreadsheet of Google Docs. In order to confirm this, can you try to run a following script?

```
var id = "1v7EShuCrjrEa8BxW2JGCRDUwuIsUk03fnvvYEVntlvM";
Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getMimeType());
```

If the log shows `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, the file is Excel file. If the log shows `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`, the file is Spreadsheet file.

In the case of Excel file, when the file is sent as an attachment file of gmail, it is not converted. Excel file can be sent. In the case of Spreadsheet file, it is converted to PDF and sent as an attachment file.

If your file was a Spreadsheet file, in order to send it as Excel file, you can use the following sample script.

#### Sample script :

```
function sendTimelist() {
  var emailAddress = 'some@mail.com';
  var mailReplyTo = 'somemore@mail.com';
  var subject = 'Timelist';
  var message = 'Here is my timelist!';

  var attachmentName = 'Timelist.xlsx';
  var fileId = "1v7EShuCrjrEa8BxW2JGCRDUwuIsUk03fnvvYEVntlvM";
  var timelist = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + fileId + "&exportFormat=xlsx",
    {
      "headers": {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    }
  ).getBlob().setName(attachmentName);
  var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo: mailReplyTo, name: attachmentName, attachments: [timelist] };

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked really well. One last thing: Where is the documentation for exporting such files?

Comment: @Thodi Welcome. I'm relieved to hear that. You can seee the document for exporting files [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export). If you want to download files except for Google Docs, you can see [this document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia).

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of the problem is using `SpreadsheetApp` to open the file. To preserve original data type, open it as `DriveApp.getFileById(...)` which returns a File object. You shouldn't need `getAs` either.

Comment: I think it’s DriveApp.getFileById(Id)